# My CN1 app crash on startup

Tags: ios, iphone, codenameone

Since today I can't run a CN1 debug the app on my iPhone 4 (iOS 9.3.5). It crashes on startup.

I've made only minor changes:
Add a button which uses `execute(URL)` to open a URL.

and I've got this exception:

> Library not loaded
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/UserNorifications.framework/UserNotifications
>   [...]
>
> Reason: image not found.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: I think you are missing some image. Check All images are placed in in your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably a regression due to changes that went in to implement https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2208

It's probably due to this commit: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/a3a70fadd7dbef661351d11dc35683be3d828eda

Can you please file an issue to keep track on this?

We're looking into it.

Comment: I have made a change that should fix this issue.  It will be included in the next server update.  https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2469